# Smaller thumbnail in the_content

Tags: post-thumbnails

My site is basically a Pinterest style product catalogue with atleast one image per post.

I upload large images, thumbnails of which are automatically generated by wordpress BUT the website has been loading really slow because `the_content` tag by default uses the largest thumbnail image that I choose from the "media" tab while creating the post.

Is there any way to use the smaller thumbnail but link to the larger thumbnail on click?

edited to add: I use the `Pinboard` theme.

I appended the following in `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(280, 800);
```

and this in `loop.php`:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail(); 
} else {
    echo("-");
}
```

but it shows the else part on the website, so I assume it isn't finding the image used?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more info please? Is it a custom theme you use? Have you tried making the default generated thumbnails smaller (to your needs) under settings->media? Have you tried a [lightbox plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=lightbox)? What do you mean by "smaller/larger thumbnail"? The default sizes are: thumb/medium/large.

Comment: @marikamitsos Sure, I edited the description

Comment: @marikamitsos I upload images from the `media` tab, then create a post and `attach` the uploaded image. Although the image shows fine on the homepage but it shows the `full` version although I can see under `uploads` that wordpress has generated all sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be unclear about the code and features you are referring to and therefore about what you are asking. If you are trying to change the size of the thumbnail for an image you are inserting in the content area then you would change this in the Settings under Media as **marikamitsos** mentioned.

Insert the image into the content area by clicking 'Add Media', selecting the image, then selecting 'Media File' from the 'Link To' drop down and 'Thumbnail' from the 'Size' dropdown as shown below. This will allow you to display the thumbnail while linking to the full size image. Also this is the thumbnail size that will reflect what you have set in the Settings under Media.

[image: Inserting a thumbnail while linking to the full size image.]

Now if you are trying to insert a 'Featured Image' as your code implies then you need to click 'Set Featured Image' from the Featured Image meta box as shown below.

[image: Set featured image.]

The size of the featured image that is displayed can then be changed as you have done in you original code above but rather than add what you did to your *functions.php* I would suggest simply adding `the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');` to your *loop.php*. This will again use the dimensions you have set in the Media Settings for thumbnails. Please note that `the_content` does *not* display the featured image.

I suspect you are seeing the result of your `else` condition because you may have not actually set the featured image. Please refer to the codex on how to get the [post thumbnail linking to the large image size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Post_Thumbnail_Linking_to_Large_Image_Size) as **varun1505** mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Post_Thumbnail_Linking_to_Large_Image_Size) will help you. It shows how to link to a larger image and display the thumbnail.

Also, if you want to display a smaller image, you can do this

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );
```

This will generate a thumbnail of size 100px by 100px.

Comment: Tried this, but returns nothing, its still the same.

Comment: can you post some code from loop.php? what exactly does loop.php do?

Comment: well its a huge file but the only relevant part is `the_content` cause its the tag that displays the featured image on the homepage, and I need that image to be a "thumbnail" instead of the larger one